# Rails LEFT OUTER JOIN with a where clause on both tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `jobs` with a relationship to a table called `job_request`.

[image]

I am trying to get all the jobs from the jobs table with the status of waiting. I also want to include the records from the job_request table where the user_id is equal to a particular user.

This is the code with the last where clause missing giving me all requests for each job:

```
@jobs = Job.includes(:job_requests).where(:status => 'waiting')
```

In other words I am looking to do the following SQL clause:

```
SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "job_requests" ON "job_requests"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" 
WHERE (jobs.status = 'waiting' OR job_requests.user_id = 1)
```

Comment: I'm not getting what you want after reading 3 times.. :p

Comment: I am also trying to understand but not getting your question.

Comment: I think he wants ALL jobs that are `waiting`, AND all `job_requests` for `current_user`. The problem is he is currently getting only jobs that are `waiting` that ALSO have a `job_request` for `current_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query if I get you.

```
@jobs = Job.includes(:job_requests)
           .where('jobs.status = ? OR job_requests.user_id = ?', 'waiting', api_current_user.id)
           .references(:job_requests)
```

Comment: I need the user_id in the other table not the one in the jobs table. That's the confusing bit.

Comment: This is what I did but it only returns the rows where there is a request by the current user. I also want all the jobs with no request from the current user.

Comment: @Mikael well.. what's the status of the jobs which has no requests..?

Comment: Also waiting. Basically one user posts a job with the status set to waiting. Many users can then request to do the job. When I am one of these users I would like to see all the jobs available and know which ones I have already requested.

Answer (score 0):

For AND conditions you need to write the SQL I believe:

```
@jobs = Job.includes(:job_requests).where('status = ? AND user_id = ?', 'waiting', api_current_user.id)
```

Comment: I need the user_id in the other table not the one in the jobs table. That's the confusing bit.